# Remembering state c++

Tags: c++, function, object, state

My application has me calling a bunch of callbacks that need to know their last state, or the state of the last invocation. A simple instance is the time difference between two successive invocations.

I know that function objects in c++ are a generic way to do that. But I am a nOOb and not sure how to set this schema up. Any help or specific simple code examples will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well... callbacks/state machines are probably *not* how you want to start learning C++....

Comment: Also, you should consider reading a good book on C++.

Comment: callback functions were a known pain in the ass in C++ until C++11 introduced bound lambdas.  Now they are nice.  You should use C++11 lambdas if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a class that implements operator(). For instance,

```
class F {
    int state;
public:
    int operator()(/*any parameters would go here*/){
        return state++;
    }
    F() : state(0) {}
};
```

You can then create and instance which will be callable and retain state.

```
F f;
f(); //returns 0
f(); //returns 1
```

Comment: How different is it from a generic function that can also be called and used to calculate the value of state in this example

Comment: @user1247384: It's an object, so it can remember its state.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the idea is that if I write a generic getter function to get state, I would not be able to remember it, as in get the last invocation value. Here above, we know the last value by virtue of just a simple invocation. Does that seem fair?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good framework for State than use FSM. There are few popular like :

http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/fsm/doc/reference.html

and

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/index.html

Its a little complicated for newbie but you will learn a lot. You can even implement your own dummy version ( not so complicated).

Fsms are really useful in embedded world, when in example class can have 20 states.